# Does locking a CPU frequency to a higher state (even OC) have any downsides?

Tags: voltage, frequency, cpu

I got into an argument with a friend that thinks generally is not a good idea to manually lock a CPU to a high frequency, or even overclocking by locking the frequency, in a stable scenario. His main argument is: why would I want it to run like that, because most of the time my computer sits idle, as if a car engine is revved without moving. But from my experience, the analogy is not quite so because a CPU locked at a high frequency and locked voltage, will barely consume anymore power in idle states than a CPU that behaves in default configuration. As an example,  from my experience, **at idle**, 4.1 GHz @ 1.35V and 1.6 GHz @ 0.6V uses roughly the same amount power.

But what about the clock cycles? Are there any advantages of having the CPU locked and ready for when the load demands high performance? Are there any disadvantages?

Wikipedia in CPU clocks states:

> After each clock pulse, the signal lines inside the CPU need time to
> settle to their new state. That is, every signal line must finish
> transitioning from 0 to 1, or from 1 to 0. If the next clock pulse
> comes before that, the results will be incorrect. In the process of
> transitioning, some energy is wasted as heat (mostly inside the
> driving transistors).

Can this count as an advantage towards locking the frequency?

I would like to know more about this from an engineering / electrical POV.

Comment: You say from your experience, what do you got to back up that? Even if a CPU is idle, it still do instructions = idling at higher Hz = more power used.

Comment: I will have to redo the experiment when I arrive at my PC and take some screentshots. Nobody disputes that idling at higher Hz = more power used, but is that significant? If it's into single digits Ws @idle, does that really matter for a high end CPU?

Comment: The dynamic power is an awful lot of power extra in a commercial PC processor, which is what you're looking at. As a simple example, when I loaded a high-end game on a previous PC the internal temperature went up 10'C and the fans went loud, still do on newers. That's power being dissipated as heat into the air. Every modern laptop (unless you force settings), tablet and phone around you is reducing the clock frequency as much as it can, ideally to zero (standby) to reduce the power it's drawing and dissipating. I think your experiment is flawed.

Comment: Does it matter if one person "disables CPU throttling" for "better performance?"  No, it will just use a "little more power."  But if *everyone in the world* did this, it would waste gigawatts/hour or more.  Society would gladly trade a tiny bit of performance for breathable air and a functional electrical grid.

Comment: Here's a quick test I made with my TR3960x with locked voltages and locked clocks, first at 1.8Ghz and the second at 3.6Ghz. So esentially double the frequency in idle, but like just 10Ws more in idle power.
https://i.imgur.com/hg4LpQM.jpg

Comment: It reads like you're trying to support your theory and seeing what you want to see, not what's there. In your [linked test results](https://i.imgur.com/hg4LpQM.jpg) you link to, it also shows an 'average effective clock' of 17.2 MHz, for example. Had you looked at that? It suggests that, during your test, the clock is being heavily throttled during CPU downtime. Beyond that, from the direction you seem to have gone in, I have to ask how likely you think that you'll exit this exercise by proving the semiconductor industry, physics and computer engineering have all had it wrong for decades?

Comment: Unfortunately stack wouldn't let me edit my own comment past 5 mins. If you look below, I replied to the below answer and that comment is complete with both scenarios I talked about. If anything your point actually props my original point in that even though I can lock the clocks via BIOS to a certain level, there are no any significant downsides in doing that, only advantages for multi core tasking. If you look at both screenshots I provided, you can see the locked clocks and locked voltages and a mere 10W delta in idle. The effective clocks are irrelevant because the tests were done at IDLE.

Comment: @TonyM Here's straight from HWInfo detailed info on effective clocks:

"Very low values are normal when the core is idling."

And hence my question and whole discussion is about idle states, as said above very low values mean nothing since guess what...the system was idle.

Comment: Well, it's actually 'guess what: the clock isn't locked', which discredits your whole point. The effective clock value, and merely the need for an effective clock value, show that. A locked clock means effective clock frequency = clock frequency, which these aren't. It's not an opinion of mine, it's just the empirical data you posted.

Answer (score 6):

> ... at idle, 4.1 GHz @ 1.35V and 1.6 GHz @ 0.6V uses roughly the same amount power.

This doesn't make sense to me.

The power consumption of a CPU can be thought as a sum of static and dynamic consumptions:

$$
P_T=P_{s}+P_{d}
$$

And dynamic consumption is directly proportional to frequency and operating voltage:

$$
P_{d}\propto \ V^2 \ f
$$

So, even if you keep the frequency constant (1.6 GHz or 4.1 GHz, doesn't matter), doubling the operating voltage (i.e. 1.35 V from 0.6 V) quadruples the dynamic consumption. For your case, unless the static consumption is high enough to neglect the dynamic consumption, which is unlikely, it doesn't seem to be possible to have the same consumption for both conditions. It's also a matter of how you measure it i.e. using a power meter to measure from wall plug *(gives total system consumption)* or using MCU's/mainboard's query routines *(gives individual component-based measurement)*.

---

As for your main question, according to the two equations above, locking the frequency to a higher value basically increases the consumption at idle. This will

- increase the heat inside the chip therefore reduce lifespan
- and bring extra unnecessary noise (assuming a fan-cooled system)

Comment: The power supply is also likely non-linear in its efficiency curve (usually bell-shaped.)  They are typically most efficient at around 50% rated load.  So use a "kill-a-watt" meter or similar to measure the *real* electrical consumption from the wall plug for best results.

Comment: @rdtsc today's CPUs have multiphase buck regulators and the controllers add or remove phases to increase light-load efficiency. Yes, the efficiency is higher at somewhere between 70 and 90 percent loading, but it's still really high at 25% or even 10% loading.

Comment: Here's a quick test I made with my TR3960x with locked voltages and locked clocks, first at 1.8Ghz and the second at 3.6Ghz. So esentially double the frequency in idle, but like just 10Ws more in idle power. Bare in mind however that this is a rather beastly CPU with 24 cores and the frequency is all core. I bet the delta in idle power gets smaller as CPU core count gets smaller, meaning it is directly correlated to how powerful the CPU is overall

<img src=https://i.imgur.com/hg4LpQM.jpg>

<img src=https://i.imgur.com/oJDMmJt.jpg>